# Finding trouble in generating the list of all Students who belongs to both the majors named as "CS" and "EE"

Tags: sql, group-by

```
Create table Students(
S_id int Primary Key,
S_name varchar(100),
Gpa float ,
Size_hs int 
)

Create  table Apply (
s_id int ,
C_name varchar(100),
Major varchar(10),
Decision varchar(2)
)


insert into Students values (123,'Amy',3.9,1000)
insert into Students values (234,'Bob',3.6,1500)
insert into Students values (345,'Craig',3.5,500)
insert into Students values (456,'Doug',3.9,1000)
insert into Students values (567,'Edward',2.9,2000)
insert into Students values (678,'Fay',3.8,200)
insert into Students values (789,'Gray',3.4,800)
insert into Students values (987,'Helen',3.7,800)
insert into Students values (876,'Irene',3.9,400)
insert into Students values (765,'Jay',2.9,1500)
insert into Students values (654,'Amy',3.9,1000)
insert into Students values (543,'Craig',3.4,2000)


insert into Apply values (123,'NJIT','CS','Y')
insert into Apply values (123,'NJIT','EE','N')
insert into Apply values (123,'Stoony Brook','CS','Y')
insert into Apply values (123,'Cornell','EE','Y')
insert into Apply values (234,'Stoony Brook','Bio','N')
insert into Apply values (345,'WPI','Bio-Eng','Y')
insert into Apply values (345,'Cornell','Bio-Eng','N')
insert into Apply values (345,'Cornell','CS','Y')
insert into Apply values (345,'Cornell','EE','N')
insert into Apply values (678,'NJIT','Hist','Y')
insert into Apply values (987,'NJIT','CS','Y')
insert into Apply values (987,'Stoony Brook','CS','Y')
insert into Apply values (876,'NJIT','Bio','N')
insert into Apply values (876,'WPI','Marine-Bio','Y')
insert into Apply values (876,'WPI','Hist','N')
insert into Apply values (765,'NJIT','Hist','Y')
insert into Apply values (765,'Cornell','Hist','N')
insert into Apply values (765,'Cornell','Psych','Y')
insert into Apply values (543,'WPI','CS','N')
```

These are the tables and insertion data with in tables.
I am having trouble finding the data listed above in the title of problem.
Basically i have to find the list of students id who belongs to both major named as 'Cs' and 'EE'.
I tried it by myself but it is not working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query:

```
select s_id 
from apply
where major in ('CS', 'EE')
group by s_id
having count(distinct major) = 2
```

returns the `s_id`s of the students that you want.
You can use it to filter the table `students`:

```
select * from students 
where s_id in (
  select s_id 
  from apply
  where major in ('CS', 'EE')
  group by s_id
  having count(distinct major) = 2
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bfbcb17a95ba0f1964d69965c04df70a).
Results:

```
> S_id | S_name | Gpa | Size_hs
> ---: | :----- | --: | ------:
>  123 | Amy    | 3.9 |    1000
>  345 | Craig  | 3.5 |     500
```